# java.io.FileNotFoundException for excel file through FileInputStream()

Tags: java

I am getting the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Selenium Reports\Daily Reports\Merged file.xls` when I am trying to access excel file through java program.

I have tried with:

1. absolute path
2. relative path
3. read/write access to the file
4. checked whether the file is open

Still, it is not working, is it not working because I have guest access to the machine?

Comment: You'd better provide the code.

Comment: what build tool and IDE are you using?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` means the file cannot be found. There really isn't much more that can be said of it.

Comment: Double your backslashes.

Comment: There is a [space] between Daily and Reports and even in the File name. Try to remove those spaces and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep the **.java** file and the **.xls** file in the same folder and use the code:

```
try {
        File f = new File("Merged file.xls");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
            if (!f.createNewFile())
                System.out.println("File cannot be created");
            else
                System.out.println("File created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File exists");
            if(!f.canRead())
                System.out.println("Error in reading. Need permission");
            if(!f.canWrite())
                System.out.println("Error in writing. Need permission");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Geet for your efforts.